# VSCode not recognising imported modules with es6 syntax

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know why VSCode isn't recognising imported es6 modules? Is it just not implemented fully yet or am I not setting it up right? I couldn't find any solutions to this from their documentation or when searching google.

I have a typings folder set up in the root directory alongside my generated jsconfig file. I've tried fiddling with the settings, adding different "module" compiler options, still doesn't work.

```
{
    // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=759670
    // for the documentation about the jsconfig.json format
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jspm_packages",
        "tmp",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

When I use `import express from 'express'` it doesn't recognise the module, but when I use `import express = require('express')` it does.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following inside your `"compilerOptions"`:

`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`